# How to prove that this two fractions are not equivalent (equal)?

Tags: arithmetic, real-numbers, fractions

We have the fractions $\frac{n+3}{n-2}$ and $\frac{2n-3}{2n-8}$. Prove that these fractions are not equivalent (equal with each other)

My ideas and what I tried:

- I tried to multiply the terms $(n+3) \times (2n-8)$ and $(n-3) \times (2n-3)$ ,and said that they are equal and try to gave them another form and to show that the premise that they are equal is false (I don't know if this works and respect the math rules),
- another solving try was to equal $(n+3)$ with $(n-2)$, etc.)
- Another try was to transform them in a inequality equation.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). If the fractions are equal, its different is zero. This happens (compute it) if and only if $n=6$. So your claim is false.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4775859/proof-that-these-fractions-are-not-equivalent-equal) was closed

Comment: a quick proof by contradiction will be as follows, assume them to be equal for all n, put n=1, As they don't come out to be equal, Hence our assumption is wrong

Answer (score 1):

With a single variable like $n$, I'm assuming you're trying to prove whether or not the equation is true for *all* real values of $n$. Therefore, if this were the case, then the desired solution is $n \in \mathbb{R}$.

To solve for $n$:

$\frac{n+3}{n-2} = \frac{n-2}{2n-8} \\
(n+3)(2n-8)=(n-2)(2n-3) \\
2n^2-2n-24=2n^2-7n+6 \\
5n = 30 \\
n = 6$

We can conclude that $n \notin \mathbb{R}$ and so the equation is not true for all values of $n$.